# Will the order of binding an event callback be sure in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have some code like this:

```
$("#start").click(function1);
$("#start").click(function2);
$("#start").click(function3);

// I need function1, function2 and function3 be all executed when
// the #start button on this page
// is clicked, and in the order that I bind them.
```

When I click the `#start` button, will the order be ALWAYS function1, function2, function3? Is there any risk that the order could be random?

Thanks,

Comment: you can specify your order in html however <div id="start" onClick="function1();function2();function3()"></div> if you want it in particulr order irrespective of defined in js

Comment: What if I have to do it in JavaScript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456312/order-of-execution-of-jquery-event-handlers-in-respect-to-inline-javascript-ev

Comment: this is a js solution only just define your function1,2,3 It will work

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920504/how-to-execute-jquery-functions-in-a-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I click the #start button, will the order be ALWAYS function1, function2, function3?

Yes. jQuery ensures it, even on browsers that don't (mostly obsolete ones now).

Simply searching for "order" [in the `on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) answers this:

> Event handlers bound to an element are called in the same order that they were bound.

Comment: So if I use native JavaScript API it's random. And if I do it with jQuery like what I did in the question, it's under guarantee?

Comment: except if there is any async processes in one of the functions there

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo: No, not random. `addEventListener` is also guaranteed to execute them in the order they were bound. Microsoft's proprietary predecessor to it, `attachEvent`, executed them in the reverse order. jQuery normalizes to the standard.

Comment: @madalinivascu: No, the handler order is guaranteed. Naturally if they start async operations, the *completion* of those operations may occur in a different order. That's irrelelvant here.

Comment: That is very helpful. Thanks very much for such a quick answer! After 9 mins (that I have to wait) I will credit you.

Answer (score 0):

How about a Snippet to <s>prove</s> **test** the point.. ->

New game, see if anyone can get the number in a different order :)

```js
function makeFn(ref) {
  return function Fn() {
    console.log(ref);
  }
}


$("#start").click(makeFn(1));
$("#start").click(makeFn(2));
$("#start").click(makeFn(3));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

Comment: Awesome. First time to see the console output this way!

Comment: An example doesn't prove anything.

Comment: That's true..  But doesn't harm.  Maybe the word prove was wrong, I maybe should have said test.  eg. Test runners of course work on this principle.

Comment: @Bergi Yes. That is what I got confused. But the other answer makes me feeling safe.

Comment: i got order different because i was looking from down :P

Comment: Crikey, how many sheeple does @Bergi have..  I mean obviously someone has seen his comment, and though oh!!, better upvote him & then downvote this as Mr Bergi has created one of his flippant remarks.. Cool..!!

Comment: yes T.J. Crowder downvoted this :P

Comment: Oh well,. Maybe he had his reasons..  But I would point out even his response is not proof, as of course bugs do happen.  I'm a little surprised as he is from the UK, I would have expected better manners.  Hope he shows his customers more respect.!!